# adding attributes to Emberjs component

Tags: ember.js

i have component like this and want to set some attributes on it:

```
OlapApp.ItemRowsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
tagName: 'li',
classNameBindings: ['currentItem.isMeasure:d_measure:d_dimension'],
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().draggable({

    });
},
actions: {
    removeItem: function(item) {
        item.deleteRecord();
        item.save();
    },
    didClick: function(item) {
        if (item.get('isMeasure')) {
            item.deleteRecord();
            item.save();
        }
    }
}
});
```

and i call this component like this :

```
{{#each item in getRowItem}}
 {{item-rows currentItem=item}}
{{/each}}
```

item have a id property `item.id` now i want to set this id to data-id of component to create an element like this :

```
<li data-id='id of item'>Some text</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after searching and trying some way i find that . im using this for solve my problem :

```
attributeBindings:['getId:data-id'],
getId:function(){return this.get('currentItem.id')}.property(),
```

Comment: Your notation of attributeBindings reminds of the notation for classNameBindings. And i am quite sure that this snippet should not do what you are looking for.

Comment: according to [customize view](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/#toc_attribute-bindings-on-a-view) i think it is correct

Comment: I have just looked into the documentation of Ember.View and didn't see it there. Thx. Learned something again :-). So my only improvment suggestions is the computed property shorthand for more readability (and the little gotcha that yours wouldn't update if the id changes) :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach actually works? I would suspect that it shouldn't work that way and should rather be:

```
OlapApp.ItemRowsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings:["data-id"],
  "data-id" : Ember.computed.oneWay("currentItem.id")
  // and the rest of your code ...
});
```

**One little extra remark:** Checkout my blog post on how to perform jquery logic correctly: http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/

Comment: i try to use your way but i get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ` and this error happen in `data-id`

Comment: Oh `data-id` isn't a valid key. Can you try to put it in quotation marks `"data-id"`?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do it without introducing an extra computed property.

```
attributeBindings:['currentItem.id:data-id']
```